# Questions about a sentence concerning rings and monoids

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, monoid

I have a first question concerning this sentence in my book.

> The ring is unital if, in addition, $(R\setminus\{0\}, \times)$ is a monoid.

I do not understand why we retrieve $0$, that is the additive identity, since for a monoid we do not have any problem at my knowledge by keeping $0$ ?

My second question is concerning the annihilator property of the additive identity $0$ in a ring, if the ring is not unital, that is it is not a monoid for the multiplicative operation, I do not see how we can prove that this property is still true: I suspect it is no more the case (since in my proof I use the multiplicative identity). Am I right ?

Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intent of this definition is to disallow $0$ from being the multiplicative unit. However, this is actually not correct. The [zero ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_ring) is unital but $0 = 1$ in that ring (and it is the unique ring in which $0 = 1$).

**Edit:** Actually this definition is even incorrect for a second reason: it requires that the product of two nonzero elements is nonzero, so it forbids [zero divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor). This is defining a [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_(ring_theory)), not a unital ring.

I don't know what "this property" is referring to in your second question.

Comment: In my mind $0$ and $1$ were naturally distincts so I have not seen the interest of this definition in my book neither the counter example you provide here, thank you a lot.  For the second question it is the following property of the additive identity : $0x = 0$ for all $x$ in the ring.

Comment: @coboy: we have $0x + 0x = (0 + 0)x = 0x$. No multiplicative identity is required.

Comment: Yes you are right thank you a lot. I totally forget about this fact $x+x = x\implies x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the intent was to later draw a parallel about fields being such that $(R,+)$ and $(R\setminus\{0\},\times)$ are both abelian groups.  Considering the case when $(R\setminus\{0\},\times)$ is a monoid is a natural relaxation of that, but as Qiaochu pointed out, $R$ has to be a domain for the binary operation to work right.

Of course, $(R,\times)$ is always a monoid (with absorbing element $0$ and identity that of $R$, if it exists.)

---

> My second question is concerning the annihilator property of the additive identity 0 in a ring, if the ring is not unital, that is it is not a monoid for the multiplicative operation, I do not see how we can prove that this property is still true:

The annihilator property does not depend on the ring having a multiplicative identity at all, just on the additive group structure and distributivity.  See, if you have any element $r\in R$, then $r0=r(r-r)=r^2-r^2=0$ (or any other convenient variation thereof.)  Not knowing what your proof is, I do not know why you feel the identity is indispensable.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer which brings another point of view. Yes, it has been pointed out to me.  After some reflexion, my proof was not correct, I assume $-(ab)=(-a)b$. The attempt was : take  $x\in R$ then : $0= x+(-x) =1x + (-1x) = 1x + (-1)x= x(1-1)=(1-1)x=0x $.